# Encrypt/Decrypt using mcrypt

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

Trying to achieve encrypting and decryption using following strategy, but ending up with random characters mostly.

```
class Crypt {

public static function encrypt($string, $account) {
    // create a random initialization vector to use with CBC encoding
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

    $key = pack('H*', $account . $account);

    $output = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $output = $iv . $output;
    $output = base64_encode($output);
    $output = urlencode($output);

    return $output;
}

public static function decrypt($token, $account) {
    $ciphertext_dec = base64_decode($token);

    // retrieves the IV, iv_size should be created using mcrypt_get_iv_size()
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, 0, $iv_size);

    // retrieves the cipher text (everything except the $iv_size in the front)
    $ciphertext_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, $iv_size);

    $key = pack('H*', $account . $account);

    $token = urldecode($token);

    $output = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec);
    $output = rtrim($output, "");
    return $output;
}

   }
```

Can't get exact values back, sometimes it decrypts but I see some garbage values, but mostly just random characters.

```
$a = \Crypt::encrypt("MyPassword", "1974246e");
echo \Crypt::decrypt($a, "1974246e");
```

---

### Edits after the discussion

```
class Crypt {

public static function encrypt($data, $passphrase) {
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC); //create a random initialization vector to use with CBC encoding
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $key = pack('H*', $passphrase . $passphrase);
    return base64_encode($iv . mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
}

public static function decrypt($data, $passphrase) {
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC); //retrieves the IV, iv_size should be created using mcrypt_get_iv_size()
    $iv = substr($data, 0, $iv_size);
    $data = substr($data, $iv_size); //retrieves the cipher text (everything except the $iv_size in the front)
    $key = pack('H*', $passphrase . $passphrase);
    return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv), chr(0));
}
}
```

Usage:

```
$pass = "MyPassword*&^*&^(*&^(";
$token = \Crypt::encrypt($pass, "1974246e8e8a479bb0233495e8a3ed12");
$answer = \Crypt::decrypt($token, "1974246e8e8a479bb0233495e8a3ed12");
echo $answer == $pass ? "yes" : "no";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't urlencode. Unnecessary.
2. trim for NULL bytes, not empty strings: `rtrim($str, chr(0));` (Instead, you might want to save the source string length in the encrypted result too, so you won't `rtrim()` too much.)

Why `pack('H*', $account)` for `$key`? Also unnecessary.

Rijndael 128 uses 16 byte keys (128 bits), so make sure your key is at least that long:

```
$key = $account . $account
```

will do, but it obviously imperfect. (`mcrypt` will do something like that if it's too short.) If every account had its own passphrase, that would be good. (Even more so in combination with an app secret, but details.)

`rtrim()` with `chr(0)` is fine, very probably, because your source string won't have trailing NUL bytes.

[I usually use these en/decrypt functions, or alike](https://github.com/rudiedirkx/Jira/blob/54ca67862310d0acbc4329b6a4bea5febf61cbfa/inc.functions.php#L96), but these have a static secret/key, so yours is better.

To send an encrypted token to the client:

```
$enc_token = Crypt::encrypt($token, $key);
// $enc_token might contain `/` and `+` and `=`
$url = 'page.php?token=' . urlencode($enc_token);
```

Comment: Thanks Rudie, I removed urlencode and added trim for unwanted characters and it works, however, I didn't get how can I avoid using $key (pack etc.) and rtrim too much, I didn't write the code but can you please edit above two functions to provide an efficient solution that doesn't use unnecessary elements.

Comment: I can avoid passing $account altogether provided that I get back my original string, also generated token should be random/different each time.

Comment: I've extended my answer, but I won't rewrite the encryption methods. They're fine mostly. Only the `rtrim()` and `urlencode()` notes are important.

Comment: You must pass $account (or something like that), because you need an en/decryption key. It could be an app secret (instead of something account specific), but the more unique, the better.

Comment: yes each account passphrase is 32 characters and every account passphrase is different, please go ahead with rewriting the encrypt and decrypt functions

Comment: $account is a string basically

Comment: Yes, I understand. The hashed password/passphrase is fine as key, just as long as the encrypted data doesn't outlive the key (password changes > key changes > can't decrypt data).

Comment: Question... 1. Don't urlencode. Unnecessary. (we have to send the token down the wire to the browser so I think url encode was necessary though it works fine without it but any thoughts?

Comment: You really shouldn't send the encryption key to the client... Only the app must know the key. The encrypted data is to share with the client, or wherever, but not the key.

Comment: we're sending the encrypted token (result from encrypt function) down the wire, I mean that's how the system (3rd party app residing on client machine, actually not browser) works, and we need to conform to that. so in that case do you think url encode is necessary?

Comment: You're encrypting the token? Yes, that's fine. You (or your framework) must urlencode the encrypted, base64 encoded result then, yes. base64 results have `/` and `+` and `=`, so those must be urlencoded. It depends on how the URL is created. Your app/library/framework **might** take care of it. Otherwise: see answer.

Comment: cool, I modified the question based on our discussion, kindly bless.

Comment: Hi Rudie: I ran into a bit of problem, as the code I built is based on this thread. please have a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049220/authtoken-encryption-with-urlencoding-urldecoding-and-htaccess-issue