# authToken encryption with urlencoding/urldecoding and .htaccess issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication, encryption, mcrypt

how to generate tokens when you have encryption with url encoding/urldecoding and .htaccess file involved.

I've a .htaccess enabled as well and it ran into a problem of javascript/php communication mentioned on this url. http://www.tequilafish.com/2007/12/06/mod_rewrite-php-how-to-match-urlencoded-plus-sign/

as per the suggestion by the post, I can't urlencode twice, as frontend system is not under my control,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

.

```
class Crypt {

public static function encrypt($data, $secret) {
   $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
   $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
   $key = pack('H*', $secret);
   return base64_encode($iv . mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
   }

public static function decrypt($data, $secret) {
   $data = base64_decode($data);
   $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
   $iv = substr($data, 0, $iv_size);
   $data = substr($data, $iv_size);
   $key = pack('H*', $secret);
   return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv), chr(0));
   }
  }
```

Comment: Better let the NSA know that you want to make things easier for them, they'll be able to prepare for all the redundancies then

Comment: I don't get the problem. You're not showing any relevant code. You want to pass the WHOLE request URI (including path, script and params) to a query param? That's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

if You want send data in url then you must use urlencode and where ever you get data urldecode. With urlencode remove all space and spacial character and urldecode you get real data

Example :

$abc = urlencode($abc);

then send it in url

redirec : [authToken encryption with urlencoding/urldecoding and .htaccess issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049220/?id=)$abc

I thing you get it :)

Comment: That's actually not true. PHP parses and decodes input. If you urlencode a `&` so the url becomes `index.php?var=%26`, you **don't** have to `urldecode($_GET['var'])` to get the `&` back. PHP does that for you.